# Is there a way to catch rows with no response from a request log file?

Tags: linux, sorting, ubuntu, logging, grep

I'm on a linux machine and have a log file with entries like these,

...

- 20170823-164549.475 THREAD RUN
- 20170823-164550.482 THREAD RUN
- 20170823-164551.499 LOG_ENTRY_FOR_55897 RequestXML: /* SOME FANCY
  REQUEST XML TEXT HERE */
- 20170823-164552.454 LOG_ENTRY_FOR_55897 ResponseXML /* AND SOME FANCY
  RESPONSE TEXT HERE */
- /* SOME THREAD RUN ROWS */
- 20170823-165438.766 LOG_ENTRY_FOR_55898 RequestXML: /* ANOTHER FANCY
  REQUEST XML TEXT HERE*/
- 20170823-165439.150 LOG_ENTRY_FOR_55898 ResponseXML /* ANOTHER FANCY
  RESPONSE XML TEXT HERE */
- /* SOME MORE THREAD RUN ROWS */

But sometimes the server is dead and sends me no response.

- 20170824-185023.126 LOG_ENTRY_FOR_56823 RequestXML: /* SOME FANCY
  REQUEST XML TEXT HERE FOR 56823 BUT THERE IS NO RESPONSE*/
- /* SOME THREAD RUN ROWS */
- 20170824-185026.421 LOG_ENTRY_FOR_56824 RequestXML: /* AS YOU CAN
  SEE, HERE IS ANOTHER REQEUST FOR 56824, NO RESPONSE FOR 56823*/

I have to get those log entries with no response. I have used GREP command and created a new text file with rows including "LOG_ENTRY" so far. (I mean this text file including no THREAD RUN rows, only request and response rows).

Example:

- -req a
- -req b
- -req c
- -res a
- -res c
- -res b (as you can see res b is after c because response for c has arrived faster, this log is not sorted)
- -req d
- -req e (and here it is, there is no response for e, only req)
- -res d
- -req f
- -res f

expected output:

- -req e

Is there a way to track these requests with no response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk. This expects that the request comes before the response but is easy to fix:

```
$ awk '$3=="RequestXML:"{a[$2]=$0} $3=="ResponseXML"{delete a[$2]} END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' file
20170824-185023.126 LOG_ENTRY_FOR_56823 RequestXML: /* SOME FANCY REQUEST XML TEXT HERE FOR 56823 BUT THERE IS NO RESPONSE*/
20170824-185026.421 LOG_ENTRY_FOR_56824 RequestXML: /* AS YOU CAN SEE, HERE IS ANOTHER REQEUST FOR 56824, NO RESPONSE FOR 56823*/
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
$3=="RequestXML:" {  # request record
    a[$2]=$0         # hash record to a, index with LOG_ENTRY_FOR string
} 
$3=="ResponseXML" {  # response record
    delete a[$2]     # delete matching request from a
} 
END {                # in the end
    for(i in a)      # loop all remaining  requests
        print a[i]   # and output them
}' file
```

I used this for testing:

```
20170823-164549.475 THREAD RUN
20170823-164550.482 THREAD RUN
20170823-164551.499 LOG_ENTRY_FOR_55897 RequestXML: /* SOME FANCY REQUEST XML TEXT HERE */
20170823-164552.454 LOG_ENTRY_FOR_55897 ResponseXML /* AND SOME FANCY RESPONSE TEXT HERE */
/* SOME THREAD RUN ROWS */
20170823-165438.766 LOG_ENTRY_FOR_55898 RequestXML: /* ANOTHER FANCY REQUEST XML TEXT HERE*/
20170823-165439.150 LOG_ENTRY_FOR_55898 ResponseXML /* ANOTHER FANCY RESPONSE XML TEXT HERE */
/* SOME MORE THREAD RUN ROWS */
But sometimes the server is dead and sends me no response.
20170824-185023.126 LOG_ENTRY_FOR_56823 RequestXML: /* SOME FANCY REQUEST XML TEXT HERE FOR 56823 BUT THERE IS NO RESPONSE*/
/* SOME THREAD RUN ROWS */
20170824-185026.421 LOG_ENTRY_FOR_56824 RequestXML: /* AS YOU CAN SEE, HERE IS ANOTHER REQEUST FOR 56824, NO RESPONSE FOR 56823*/
```

**Edit:** To fix the *the text 'RequestXML:' and the shortened XML text are not seperated, there is no space there* we stop doing exact comparison `$3=="..."` and instead use regex matching `$3~/^.../`:

```
$ awk '$3~/^RequestXML:/{a[$2]=$0} $3~/^ResponseXML/{delete a[$2]} END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' file
```

Comment: That's the perfect answer for given text, but I have a problem, the text 'RequestXML:' and the shortened XML text are not seperated, there is no space there, my bad. I think awk gets the whole string (RequestXML:<bla>bla....), I'll try some regex if I can. Thank you very much, nice work.

Comment: I think I had edit my comment above before your fast reply but it seems untouched so I'm adding a new comment here. I have spent a few seconds to replace 'RequestXML:' texts in the file with 'RequestXML: ' (space at the end) using vim, made it suitable for your script and your script worked well. I didn't test your edited answer (which is using regex now) but I'm sure it will work perfect as well. Thank you again.